# How to change text label with respect to slider in JQM?

Tags: ios, html, jquery-mobile, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I am using Jquerymobile. I have a slider and a text box corresponding to that. As default functionality is given value shows in the text field when we move the slider as per  the range we defined. But I want to show text instead of numbers. It's more like severity issues.
i.e: when slider value will go to 30 it should display "less sever " in textbox and when it reaches to  50, text should change to "more sever".

Comment: If you post your code, or a jsbin.com of a what you currently have, it will help a lot.

Comment: <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
                <label for="slider-a">Elegir gravedad:</label>
                <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider-a" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="e" value="0" min="0" max="100"  />
            </div>

Comment: this is my slider code..

Answer (score 2):

the solution of @Jeemusu did not work for me in all cases...
I therefore modified it using [this info](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-execute-javascript-code-when-finger-is-lifted-from-a-slider):

```
<script>
$(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
  //depending on the device we have a touch or a mouse event
  var supportTouch = jQuery.support.touch,
      touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
      touchStopEvent  = supportTouch ? "touchend"   : "mouseup",
      touchMoveEvent  = supportTouch ? "touchmove"  : "mousemove";

  //the event is bound to the .ui-slider inside of the input type range
  $('#slider-a').siblings('.ui-slider').bind(touchStopEvent,function(){
    var sliderVal = $("#slider-a").attr('value');

    if(sliderVal <= 30) {
      $('#slider-phrase').html('normal');
    } else if(sliderVal >= 30 && sliderVal < 50) {
      $('#slider-phrase').html('less severe');
    } else if(sliderVal >= 50) {
      $('#slider-phrase').html('more severe');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

see [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/suR7H/)

Answer (score 1):

All you should have to do is look for the anchor (used for the slider) created by jQuery Mobile, and then bind a tap event to it. In the tap event you can check for the value using conditional statements and output them to the page like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var sliderAnchor = $("#slider-a").closest('div').children('div').children('a');

  sliderAnchor.bind('tap',function(e){

    var sliderVal = $("#slider-a").attr('value');

    if(sliderVal <= 30) {
       $('#slider-phrase').html('normal');
    } else if(sliderVal >= 30 && sliderVal < 50) {
       $('#slider-phrase').html('less severe');
    } else if(sliderVal >= 50) {
       $('#slider-phrase').html('more severe');
    }

  });

});
```

A working example: http://jsbin.com/igugac/1/

Comment: +1 this solution gave me a good starting point for my solution, thank you!